# How do I create a .p12 file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I've looked at the [Ruby OpenSSL documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/index.html), but I can't quite figure out the pieces I need to put together to make a .p12 file.

There's also [this tutorial](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/576), but the comments belie an ambivalence about its correctness.

Answer (score 2):

From ossl_pkcs12.c:

```
/*
* call-seq:
*    PKCS12.create(pass, name, key, cert [, ca, [, key_pbe [, cert_pbe [, key_iter [, mac_iter [, keytype]]]]]])
*
* === Parameters
* * +pass+ - string
* * +name+ - A string describing the key.
* * +key+ - Any PKey.
* * +cert+ - A X509::Certificate.
* * * The public_key portion of the certificate must contain a valid public key.
* * * The not_before and not_after fields must be filled in.
* * +ca+ - An optional array of X509::Certificate's.
* * +key_pbe+ - string
* * +cert_pbe+ - string
* * +key_iter+ - integer
* * +mac_iter+ - integer
* * +keytype+ - An integer representing an MSIE specific extension.
*
* Any optional arguments may be supplied as nil to preserve the OpenSSL defaults.
*
* See the OpenSSL documentation for PKCS12_create().
```

*/

So (untested and probably incorrect - I am not very familiar with Ruby):

```
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.create("password", "key", pkey, cert)
p12_bytes = p12.to_der
```